# slice data at condition+1

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, slice

I have a df I want to merge and slice with another one, but I want to slice at a certain condition + 1.

```
 set.seed(1)
 df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=20,ncol=3))
 colnames(df1) <- c("group","trial","hour")
 df1$group <- rep(c("a","b"),each=10)
 df1$trial <- rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),times=2)
 df1$hour <- rep(c(1,11,21,31,41),times=4) 


 df2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3))
 colnames(df2) <- c("group","trial","end")
 df2$group <- c("a","a","b","b")
 df2$trial <- c(1,2,1,2)
 df2$end <- runif(4,1,40)
```

I have values every 10 hours, and each trial ends at some point between those hours. I want to merge and trim the dfs so I have each individual up until the hour they end and also one more. 
I have rows on hours 1, 11, 21, 31, 41. So if group A2 ends at 15.5 hours, I want the new df to include hour 1,11, and 21 for that group/trial.

I figured out how to filter for under the trial:

```
 df2 %>% 
   left_join(df1,by=c("group","trial")) %>%
   group_by(group,trial) %>%
   filter(hour<= end)
```

but I also want to keep one row after the "end"

I thought maybe I could use

```
 df2 %>% 
   left_join(df1,by=c("group","trial")) %>%
   group_by(group,trial) %>%
   slice(1:n(hour<= end)+1)`
```

but that didn't work.

The output I want is:

```
        group trial   end  hour
    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
  1 a         1  11.4     1
  2 a         1  11.4    11
  3 a         1  11.4    21
  6 a         2  15.5     1
  7 a         2  15.5    11
  8 a         2  15.5    21
 11 b         1  23.3     1
 12 b         1  23.3    11
 13 b         1  23.3    21
 14 b         1  23.3    31
 16 b         2  36.4     1
 17 b         2  36.4    11
 18 b         2  36.4    21
 19 b         2  36.4    31
 20 b         2  36.4    41
```

So that every group/trial retains rows for up until their "end" and one further.

Comment: Do you need `slice({i1 <- which(hour <= end); c(i1, tail(i1, 1) + 1)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear about the expected.  If the intention is to get next row after the last row where `hour <= end`, then create the position index with `which` and concatenate by adding 1 at the last index

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1,by=c("group","trial")) %>% 
  group_by(group,trial) %>% 
  slice({i1 <- which(hour <= end)
        c(i1, tail(i1, 1) + 1)})
```